# TypeCasting for string type to string

Tags: c++, string

This seems to be rather tedious but the requirement is below.
I am getting input from an application which is string and is the datatype which i need to typecast to my pointer type.

But the typecasting supports only physical appearance not the string type for ex

```
 string a = "char";
 char b;
 int c = 82;

 b= (a)c;
```

Here i need the typecasting of int c into char c and put in char b.
I need to do in loop so macros wont be useful as its preprocessor

Comment: What do you mean by `b = (a)c`? Would you want to define a new type? Your question is not clear.

Comment: what are you expecting as value of `b`?

Comment: `b` is always a `char` ?

Comment: I recommend taking the [rubber duck debugging method](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) before asking a question to make sure the question asked makes sense. This made none.

Comment: I think what you're asking is to be able to cast to a type which is defined in the string a. In this case a char, but if a was "float" then you'd want to cast to a float? This is similar to reflection, but AFAIK reflection is not supported in C++

Comment: Do you want to perform the type of cast depending on the contents of string a?

Comment: You should get a good night sleep and answer "Here i need the typecasting of int c into char c and put in char b. I need to do in loop so macros wont be useful as its preprocessor" yourself.

Comment: Can you show us what the full assignment looks like? You explained it in a very bad way.

Comment: Apologies thats my first question so kinda confusing. I wanted to typecast depending upon the contents of string as i have various user defined types in my application.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have to cast some input 'c' to some type 'b' the only way I can see doing this would be to test the user input and build in all of the supported cast. Something along the lines of this.

```
string a;

cin >> a;
a.to_lower();

for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    a[i] = tolower(a[i]);

if(a.compare("char"))
{
    c = static_cast<char>(b);
}
else if(a.compare("int"))
{
    c = static_cast<int>(b);
}
else if(...)
{
    //other supported type cast.
}
```

It's the only way I can see this being possible with the use of base types.

The other solution would be to not use base types for your input 'c' and instead use some form of abstraction like a class to handle the conversion and return the converted value and not use a typecast all together.

Comment: C style casts are evil. implicitly const casting being just one of them. Please use the casts provided by C++

Comment: Appreciate it. My mistake.

Comment: thanks Matt. This Helped me but i may like to use your other idea where calss can handle the conversion and return the converted values